# DPFPApi how to convert data_blob to qpixmap in qt5

Tags: qt, qt5, qpixmap

I'm currently integrating DigitalPersona U.are.U into a Qt Application. I've been able to obtain image DATA_BLOB from the DPFPApi. The only problem I have now is to preview the image by setting pixmap to a QLabel. I've tried using

```
QPixmap pix(QByteArray((const char*)imgBlob->pbData, imgBlob->cbData));
```

but that returns a null pixmap. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What's the format of the image blob? PNG? JPEG? BMP?

Comment: I guess the format BMP

Comment: This is an image obtained from a Fingerprint Scanner. I'm not so sure of the format

Comment: You can dump the image data to a file and try different extensions until one works then use the appropriate QPixamp function to load that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is a bitmap, use the `QBitmap::fromData` function to create the `QPixmap`. It is documented [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbitmap.html#fromData).

Or use `QPixmap::loadFromData` to allow Qt to attempt to detect the data format based on information in the image header.

Comment: I tried using the `QBitmap::fromData` function to create `QPixmap`. It displayed some jagonz similar to blackberry qr code. Then I tried using `QPixmap::loadFromData` but it return a null pixmap

Comment: Can you share the data blob so I can give it a try (if you don't mind sharing your fingerprint)?

Comment: Using `qDebug()<< imgBlob` I got `0x2377fa0`

Comment: Sorry, I can't access your pointer. Create a `QByteArray` out of the data and then `qDebug() << byteArray.toHex()`.

Comment: `qDebug()<< QByteArray((const char*)imgBlob->pbData).toHex()` gave `b43204`

Comment: How about `qDebug() << QString(byteArray.toBase64());` then?

Comment: `qDebug()<< QByteArray(QByteArray((const char*)imgBlob->pbData).toBase64())` gave `tDIE`. This is strange

Comment: The complete command should be: `qDebug() << QString(QByteArray((const char*)imgBlob->pbData, imgBlob->cbData).toBase64());`. Otherwise `QbyteArray` will end at the first NULL character.

Comment: That also gave `tDIE`. I think there is a problem somewhere

Comment: How large is the data? What's the value of `imgBlob->cbData`?

Comment: The value is `275124`

Comment: Strange. Well, if you can find a way to save the data to a file and share it with me, I'll take a look.